# Cordova ios watch live video streaming ApiRTC

Tags: ios, cordova

I am using cordova ios app for live streaming. I am able to stream video from iphone but when i try to join stream it never calls `remoteStreamAddedHandler` function to display streaming video.

I am using `cordova-plugin-iosrtc` plugin. It also shows status that "someone has joined room" but not calling that `remoteStreamAddedHandler` where i can append video tag from. It is working fine in andriod phone.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

remoteStreamAddedHandler event is fired when a remote user has already joined the room and published his stream.

On apiRTC tutorial : 11-VIDEO CALL STREAMING, user only subscribe to available streams (there is no video publish)
You need to have an user connected with tutorial 10-GROUP CALL, this user will publish his stream and subscribe to remote streams.

The tutorial 12-GROUP CALL - ADVANCED shows you an advanced sample where user can choose to publish/subscribe streams.